# Аргументы Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(`/test`)){
    const args = message.content.slice(`/test`).split(/ +/);
    if (!args[1]) {
        message.reply(`\`/test 1\``).then(msg => msg.delete(9000));
        return message.delete();
    }
    if (!args[1]  == '1') {
        message.reply(`Nice`);
    }
}
```

В боте должна быть функция когда я прописываю /test он должен ответить "/test 1", а когда я пишу /test 1 он должен ответить "Nice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, забыли убрать логический оператор НЕ из второй проверки. Уберите его, иначе условие выполняется только, если что-то кроме args[1] равно 1.

Выглядеть должно так

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`/test`)){
    const args = message.content.slice(`/test`).split(/ +/);
    if (!args[1]) {
        message.reply(`\`/test 1\``).then(msg => msg.delete(9000));
        return message.delete();
    }
    if (args[1]  == '1') {
        message.reply(`Nice`);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как это должно выглядеть в коде?